# Simple Wikipedia Text into Plain Text Parser?

Tags: parsing, text, wiki, markup

I'm searching for a simple parser that translates a String with wiki markup code to readable plain text, e.g.

```
A lot of these sources can also be used to add to other parts of the article, like the plot section. <font color="silver">[[User:Silver seren|Silver]]</font><font color="blue">[[User talk:Silver seren|seren]]</font><sup>[[Special:Contributions/Silver seren|C]]</sup> 05:34, 22 March 2012 (UTC)
```

to

```
A lot of these sources can also be used to add to other parts of the article, like the plot section. SilverserenC 05:34, 22 March 2012 (UTC)
```

I tried it with DKPro JWPL (where also the above example comes from) but this framework plain text output doesn't parse wiki talk pages (discussions) in the right way. It simply deletes lines that start with a number of ":" characters which are crucial for the talk pages.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out that the old wikipedia parser from JWPL is working: "de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia.parser"
[link](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22de.tudarmstadt.ukp.wikipedia.parser%22)

You can use it like:

```
MediaWikiParserFactory pf = new MediaWikiParserFactory(Language.english);
MediaWikiParser parser = pf.createParser();
ParsedPage pp = parser.parse("some wiki code with markups");
System.out.println(pp.getText());
```